# To use or using

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between these sentences:

Schools should start **to use** the computers;
Schools should start **using** the computers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I read [the question that this question is supposed to be a duplicate](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26101/what-is-the-difference-between-gerund-and-infinitive) and I couldn't find any difference explained there better than the syntactical one. In my opinion, this is a good question, and if it's a duplicate, it should be a duplicate of some other question, not that one.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Maybe if the question is edited to focus on the usage of the two forms. At present it's broad enough that the answer to the other question also answers this.

Comment: @starsplusplus I humbly beg to differ. For one thing, we recently welcomes other similar questions (such as [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27438/poroshenko-s-role-is-to-reassure-why-the-infinitive-form) and [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26948/start-and-begin-is-there-a-difference)) well enough. For another, I believe that if it's a duplicate, it should be a duplicate of some other question that the answers there should discuss the difference more specifically to "start to verb" vs. "start verb-ing". It's a bit broad, but not too broad for our site, I believe.

Comment: Being someone who maintains such as opinion, I took an opportunity to do a little searching. Here are a couple of questions I think better than the suggested one: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15378/should-we-always-use-verb-ing-structure-after-the-verb-start, http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/11057/3281.